# Фонематическая транскрипция слова «сестёр»

Tags: фонология

Как будет выглядеть фонематическая транскрипция слова *сестёр* в соответствии с П(Л)ФШ? МФШ? какой-либо другой (разумной) системой?

Кажется, по МФШ там гиперфонема: < c' э/о с т' о р >.

Comment: По МФШ гиперфонема только вторая С. Обе гласные фонемы О (сестры, сестер)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел от ответ от Граммы.ру.

Действительно, есть лингвисты (сторонники так называемой  Московской фонологической школы), которые считают, что звуковые оболочки словоформ могут состоять не только из фонем, но и из гиперфонем. Гиперфонемами они называют прежде всего такие фонологические единицы, которые находятся в слабой позиции и фонемная принадлежность которых не может быть установлена в данной морфеме по сильной позиции. Напр., безударный гласный в первом слоге словоформы собака нельзя проверить по сильной позиции, и это будет гиперфонема ; второй гласный находится в сильной позиции (под ударением) и это фонема ; третий гласный в окончании проверяется по сильной позиции (ср. вод-а́), и это тоже фонема . Однако, кроме таких случаев, когда проверка звука слабой позиции невозможна, некоторые представители МФШ (М.В. Панов, Л.Л. Касаткин и др.) считают гиперфонемами и такие звуки слабых позиций, для которых возможна двоякая проверка звуком в сильной позиции. Таков приведенный Вами из интернета пример со словоформой лебедь: здесь безударный гласный [и] реализует гиперфонему  **(ср. лебёдушка/лебяжий).** То же самое можно сказать и о безударном гласном в словоформе сестёр, который можно проверить по сильной позиции двояким образом: ср. сёстры (в сильной позиции под ударением ) и сестрин, сестринский (под ударением ). Таким образом, в словоформе сестёр первый гласный реализует гиперфонему **.** Разумеется, согласный **[c’]** в словоформе сестёр тоже реализует гиперфонему **<с’/з’>**, т. к. он находится в слабой позиции по глухости/звонкости и при этом не может быть проверен по сильной позиции. Таким образом, с точки зрения МФШ, звуковая оболочка словоформы сестёр [с’ис’т’ор] представляет собой последовательность фонем и гиперфонем **<с’е/ос’/з’т’ор>.** Кроме МФШ, никакие другие фонологические школы (Щербовская, Пражская, американский дескриптивизм и др.) не признают существования таких единиц, как гиперфонемы, но и в МФШ существуют различные трактовки понятия гиперфонема.